# Cisco Spark: "Failed to get activity" when retrieving messages as a bot

Tags: rest

If I do an API request to list the messages in a channel (a `GET` against the `/messages` endpoint) in the API explorer it returns a list of messages  just fine. But when I switch the credentials out for my bot it returns a "Failed to get activity" error message like so:

```
{
    "message": "Failed to get activity.",
    "errors": [
        {
            "description": "Failed to get activity."
        }
    ],
    "trackingId": "ROUTER_5AEA3971-BCE9-01BB-1880-CCEB72A21880"
}
```

How do I get the API to work with bot credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bots can only see messages in a channel when:

1. The bot has been added to the channel
2. The bot was mentioned in the message - bots can't see messages that don't @mention them!
3. The `/messages` endpoint was called with the parameter `mentionedPeople=me` in either the query string or the JSON body.

In your case you do not have `mentionedPeople=me` in the query string so it won't work.

Comment: In addition, mentionedPeople=me may be REQUIRED in the request